# Help with the Ricci tensor and Chistoffel Symbols

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, curvature

I really am confused with certain notations of the Ricci tensor and the Christoffel symbols.

I'm looking to evaluate $R_{00}$ from my lecture notes, but I'm a little stuck at one point. The Ricci tensor, $R_{\mu\nu}$ is quoted as:

$$
R_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}-\partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\lambda}+\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda\rho}\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu\rho}
$$
Now, for $R_{00}$ I evaluate:
$$
R_{00}=\partial_{\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{00}-\partial_{0}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{0\lambda}+\Gamma^{\lambda}_{\lambda\rho}\Gamma^{\rho}_{00}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{0\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{0\rho}
$$
Now, all the terms with subscript $00$ vanish, leaving:
$$
R_{00}=-\partial_{0}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{0\lambda}-\Gamma^{\rho}_{0\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}_{0\rho}
$$
Exchanging $\lambda=i$ and $\rho=j$, gives:
$$
R_{00}=-\partial_{0}\Gamma^{i}_{0i}-\Gamma^{j}_{0i}\Gamma^{i}_{0j}
$$
My metric is given as a straight forward FRW metric, i.e., $g_{ij}=\mathrm{diag}[1,-a^{2}(t),-a^{2}(t),-a^{2}(t)]$.

The lecture notes then skip a few steps and give:
$$
R_{00}=-\frac{d}{dt}\,\,3\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)-3\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^{2}.
$$
How would these steps be filled in for the metric given?

I'm equally frustrated as I can't seem to evaluate the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^{i}_{0j}$ and $\Gamma^{j}_{0i}$ to match up with the given value for $R_{00}$. Maybe that would help to start by running through the correct calculation for $\Gamma^{i}_{0j}$ and $\Gamma^{j}_{0i}$. This is the part that I think I'm not getting right.

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain the vote to close.

Comment: I would guess it's because you're asking us to do a routine calculation for you (of the Christoffel symbols) without any indication that you've made the effort yourself. In addition the calculation and results can be found with some determined Googling e.g. [in section 1.2.1 here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Chapter1.pdf). So 1 out of 10 for effort. Having said that I didn't downvote and I would have answered if Cervantes hadn't beaten me to it.

Comment: @JohnRennie I have attempted the Christoffel symbols, but as explained in the question that is where I believe I am going wrong.

Comment: @JohnRennie I see we are also having discussions on Cervantes' question. Would gladly welcome a more expanding explanation. Should I update on my attempts at evaluating the Christoffel symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Christoffel symbols for your metric are 
$$
\begin{split}
&\Gamma^0_{ij}=a\dot{a}\gamma_{ij}\\
&\Gamma^i_{0j}=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^i_j\\
&\Gamma_{jl}^{i}=\tilde\Gamma^i_{jl}
\end{split}
$$
then 
$$
R_{00}=-\partial_{0}\Gamma^{i}_{0i}-\Gamma^{j}_{0i}\Gamma^{i}_{0j}=-\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^i_i\right)-\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^i_j\right)\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^i_j\right)
$$
Then using $\delta^i_i=3$ you obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thankyou. So, using what you have qouted for $\Gamma^{i}_{0j}$ can I assume that for $\Gamma^{i}_{0i}$ we simply exchange the $j$ indice in $\delta^{i}_{j}$ for an $i$? Also, could I ask how you came to the results for the Christoffel symbols given and also how $\delta^{i}_{i}=3$...

Comment: @DarthPlagueis: did you look at the paper I linked? That goes through a sample calculation.

Comment: @JohnRennie Hi Jon. I did, thank you. It is somewhat helpful, I seem to be able to evaluate some Chistoffel symbols correctly, however, for example, I can't seem to show $\Gamma^{i}_{0j}=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\delta^{i}_{j}$...and therein lies my problem - I believe I am not quite understanding this very elementary method. Very frustrating.

Comment: @JohnRennie Also, I believe that Cervantes had it correctly first time round for $\Gamma^{0}_{ij}=a\dot{a}g_{ij}$. That might need to be rolled back. (I'm aware the Cambridge notes has it differently, as their metric is slightly more complex than the simplistic one I have given).